# Contact Form Script Ajax Doesn't Recognize the correct Result Coming From Mail.php

Tags: javascript, jquery

My mail.php return "1" when I click "Send Message" button and I receive the message as well; however it doesn't response with my script in my html file. The script is suppose to display the success message after you send the message. At the moment I keep getting the error message which is coming from my script. Does anybody has any idea? The script code is below. I look through so many similar issues posted on StackOverFlow but I don't get any luck yet. I spent two days try to find the solution. I really appreciate if anybody comes up with the right solution. Thanks!

```
<script>    
            $("#submitForm").submit(function(event) {
                /* Act on the event */

        event.preventDefault();

            $("#submit").val("Message Sending...");

                $.ajax({   
                    url: 'mail.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#submitForm').serialize(),
                        success:function(data){
                            if ($.trim(data) == '1') {  
                                swal({
                                    title: "Message Sent",
                                    text: "Mark will be in touch shortly.",
                                    icon: "success",
                                    timer:3000
                                });
                                $('#submitForm')[0].reset();
                                $("#submit").val("Send Message");
                                }else{
                                    swal({
                                        title: "Failed!",
                                        text: "Something Wrong. Please try after sometime.",
                                        icon: "warning",
                                        timer:3000
                                    });
                                    $("#submit").val("Send Message");
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: Well, first of all, your code is so old-school :p Basically, if the data is "1", what you're saying is impossible. Which means that data is not "1". Do `console.log(data)` and see what's going on.

Comment: You are right. I did console.log(data) as you suggested. It doesn't recognize the data at all. It says error:   <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/content/08/10304008/html/gd.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />

Comment: Then it recognizes the data. It's a PHP error. That's where the problem is.

Comment: What should I do? My mail.php is working correctly. I tested through my life server and able to send out the message. Can you give me any suggestion by looking at the script code above?